# Ackermann Function - Book recommendation

Tags: soft-question, advice, book-recommendation, ackermann-function

What books would you recommend me for the topic "Ackermann Function" ??

I will have a presentation at the end of the semester for this topic and I would get some information...

Comment: You can start with George Tourlakis, [Ackermann’s Function](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~gt/papers/Ackermann-function.pdf).

Comment: You can see also George Tourlakis, [Theory of Computation](https://books.google.it/books?id=DkhYBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA148) (2012) : **Ch.2.4.1 The Ackermann Function**, page 148.

Answer (score 1):

I just found some related PDFs. One has already been shared in your comments.

There doesn't seem to be any textbook solely dedicated to the Ackermann function; those textbooks which do mention it, often don't give enough information (At least not as much as the following papers...)

1. http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~gt/papers/Ackermann-function.pdf
2. http://history.dcs.ed.ac.uk/archive/docs/Imp_Benchmarks/ack.pdf
3. http://history.dcs.ed.ac.uk/archive/docs/Imp_Benchmarks/ackpe.pdf
4. http://history.dcs.ed.ac.uk/archive/docs/Imp_Benchmarks/acklt.pdf
5. http://cgi.di.uoa.gr/~ewcg06/invited/Seidel.pdf
6. http://www.saylor.org/site/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/Ackermann-Function.pdf